# SQL Server 2012 Delete From Small Table Very Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 711 record in it.

Here is the table:

```
USE [wynparts_aspdnsf]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]    Script Date: 3/10/2014 5:06:36 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists](
    [Penta_Nbr] [numeric](15, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ListType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ListData] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Some of the `ListData` can get quite big.

I'm trying to run a `DELETE` statement like:

`DELETE FROM WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists WHERE Penta_Nbr = 48855`

It is taking 4 minutes or longer to do this on the bigger records. My query plan is quite simple, there are only 4 steps. Only 3 records are deleted with this command. There are no triggers or anything.

Execution Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.3373.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="0" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0332862" StatementText="DELETE [WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]  WHERE [Penta_Nbr]=@1" StatementType="DELETE" QueryHash="0x418A7DF29AF7A9A0" QueryPlanHash="0x9230291B34359B04" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="192">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="183477" EstimatedPagesCached="14775" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="3E-06" EstimateIO="0.03" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Delete" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Delete" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0332862">
              <OutputList />
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="3" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Update DMLRequestSort="false">
                <Object Database="[wynparts_aspdnsf]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" IndexKind="Heap" />
                <Object Database="[wynparts_aspdnsf]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" Index="[IX_WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                <Object Database="[wynparts_aspdnsf]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" Index="[IX_WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists_Penta_Nbr]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="1E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032832">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="3" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Top RowCount="true" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                    <TopExpression>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                        <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </TopExpression>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="711">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="3" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[wynparts_aspdnsf]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" Index="[IX_WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists_Penta_Nbr]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                        <SeekPredicates>
                          <SeekPredicateNew>
                            <SeekKeys>
                              <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                <RangeColumns>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[wynparts_aspdnsf]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]" Column="Penta_Nbr" />
                                </RangeColumns>
                                <RangeExpressions>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(15,0),[@1],0)">
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1008">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Convert DataType="numeric" Precision="15" Scale="0" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Identifier>
                                                <ColumnReference Column="@1" />
                                              </Identifier>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Convert>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </ColumnReference>
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </RangeExpressions>
                              </Prefix>
                            </SeekKeys>
                          </SeekPredicateNew>
                        </SeekPredicates>
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Top>
                </RelOp>
              </Update>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="(48855)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(48855)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Why wouldn't this take less than a second? What can I do to make it faster?

**UPDATE**

I was checking for locks per an answer below and received this, which I don't really understand.

```
TEXT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             session_id request_id  start_time              status                         command                          sql_handle                                                                                                                         statement_start_offset statement_end_offset plan_handle                                                                                                                        database_id user_id     connection_id                        blocking_session_id wait_type                                                    wait_time   last_wait_type                                               wait_resource                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    open_transaction_count open_resultset_count transaction_id       context_info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       percent_complete estimated_completion_time cpu_time    total_elapsed_time scheduler_id task_address       reads                writes               logical_reads        text_size   language                                                                                                                         date_format date_first quoted_identifier arithabort ansi_null_dflt_on ansi_defaults ansi_warnings ansi_padding ansi_nulls concat_null_yields_null transaction_isolation_level lock_timeout deadlock_priority row_count            prev_error  nest_level  granted_query_memory executing_managed_code group_id    query_hash         query_plan_hash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ---------------- ------------------------- ----------- ------------------ ------------ ------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------------- ---------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- ------------ ---------- ----------------------- --------------------------- ------------ ----------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ---------------------- ----------- ------------------ ------------------
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext                                                                                                                                              59         0           2014-03-11 08:02:36.890 running                        SELECT                           0x02000000BD1AA61696485297D5100F2547B979F25F10C2830000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                         0                      -1                   0x06000500BD1AA616F09E44FE0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                         5           1           BAD34569-6E35-4945-8F9F-E1C46F3CF791 0                   NULL                                                         0           MISCELLANEOUS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0                      1                    19335541             0x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0                0                         0           0                  1            0x00000000C20ED498 0                    0                    0                    2147483647  us_english                                                                                                                       mdy         7          1                 1          1                 0             1             1            1          1                       2                           -1           0                 2                    0           0           0                    0                      1           0x4AC3E94A42400E47 0xB94AAAF5F1DB9778
(@1 int)DELETE [WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]  WHERE [Penta_Nbr]=@1                                                                                                                                                                                                   62         0           2014-03-11 08:02:12.820 suspended                      DELETE                           0x0200000015ABE50126BD79096518C75D9209AA1B9DC3DBF60000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                         16                     -1                   0x0600050015ABE501409D44FE0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                         5           1           70353187-2595-4D08-9F9C-E608E6FACEA6 0                   PAGEIOLATCH_EX                                               13          PAGEIOLATCH_EX                                               5:1:1047189                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2                      1                    19335431             0x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0                0                         156         24064              1            0x00000000C20ED0C8 4863                 14                   20863                2147483647  us_english                                                                                                                       mdy         7          1                 1          1                 0             1             1            1          1                       2                           -1           0                 0                    0           0           0                    0                      1           0x418A7DF29AF7A9A0 0x9230291B34359B04

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I used the following command and determined that no other tables have foreign key references to this table: `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(R.CONSTID) FROM SYSREFERENCES R WHERE R.RKEYID = OBJECT_ID('WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists')`

**RESOLUTION**

I had an index on the primary keys of Penta_Nbr & ListType (it is a multi-field primary key). It turns out that this index wasn't useful for deleting records just by Penta_Nbr. Creating another index on Penta_Nbr fixed my performance issues. This delete operation now takes less than 1 second.

Comment: Maybe blocking issues. The statement should indeed complete instantly, almost no matter what the schema is.

Comment: If Penta_Nbr is unique, perhaps make it a primary key. I personally never create a table without a primary key, as it tends to bite you at some stage of the game.

Comment: Is your table referenced by another table by a FK?

Comment: @thepirat000 I'm 99% sure it isn't; how should I confirm that?

Comment: @cjbarth try with this: `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(R.CONSTID) FROM SYSREFERENCES R WHERE R.RKEYID = OBJECT_ID('WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be caused by multiple factors. The main two are locks and waits.

Start the execution of your command and then in a new query window execute the following query:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

This will return a list of the currently running queries (this is a slightly modified [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/) query).

Next, look to the first column and select the row with your query. Here are some columns you will have to look at after:

- **status** : If it is running, that is fine. If it is Suspended then look to the rest
- **blocking_session_id** : If another session/query is blocking yours from executing (a lock issue) then this column will include the Id. You can use `EXEC sp_who2` to get a picture about the blocking session.
- **wait_type** : If no blocking session is available, then the query is waiting for something. This column will tell you what it is. More details about wait types can be found [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx)
- **wait_time** : If this is too high than you have a serious problem. The value is in milliseconds. Short wait times are fine, specially in PAGEIOLATCH wait types (access to physical files).
- **last_wait_type** : Indicates if the last wait type was different. This is quite helpful in analyzing if the query is running of blocked for the same reason.

You can go though the rest of the columns and try to understand the values. Here is a [full description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx).

In case a blocking session exist, simply try to kill it using the following command:

```
KILL blocking_session_id --replace by the actual Id, usually > 50
```

**EDIT :**

I was able to extract the relevant rows/columns from the result you posted back:

```
TEXT                                                              session_id status       command    blocking_session_id wait_type           wait_time   last_wait_type   wait_resource    reads    writes   logical_reads   
----------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------- -------- -------- ----------------
(@1 int)DELETE [WR_SPL_PreCompiledLists]  WHERE [Penta_Nbr]=@1    62         suspended    DELETE     0                   PAGEIOLATCH_EX      13          PAGEIOLATCH_EX   5:1:1047189      4863     14       20863
```

If you follow the analysis I mentioned before:

- The **status** is `suspended`
- The **blocking_session_id** is `0`, which means there is no locks issue
- The **wait_type** is `PAGEIOLATCH_EX`. Your query is waiting for the data to be read from the physical disk before running the filter on it (`WHERE Penta_Nbr = 48855`).
- The **wait_time** (per resource) is low, which means your data is divided on many pages (total runtime/wait_time).
- The **last_wait_type** is the same --> That is your problem !!

What is `PAGEIOLATCH_EX` ?

I found a good article from RedGate about it:

- http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SM4/PAGEIOLATCH_EX

I am really suspecting that the XML data is large in your tables. My suggestions will be

1. Create an index on the `Penta_Nbr` if you don't already have one
2. Run a disk defragmentation or a [file defragmentation](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3008/solving-sql-server-database-physical-file-fragmentation/)

Comment: Would this apply if it takes this long to delete every single time I run the command?

Comment: As long as you can get this query to run at the same time the other one is running yes, it applies. If the DELETE statement is done, then it will disappear from this query result.

Comment: It doesn't seem that anything is blocking the statement. I've updated my question to reflect that.